# MSTest Assert Fail messages are less useful

Tags: visual-studio, mstest

When running MS Test, all we get is a

```
Message: Assert.IsTrue failed.
```

But there are many Assert.IsTrue in the test method. So wouldn't it be helpful if we could add a custom message which will appear along this message above? At least the line number of the line it failed? This has been annoying me for a long time.

Have I missed out on any hack or useful feature from VS or MS test to tackle this?

Comment: You should be able to click on the failed test in the 'Test Explorer' and it should take you to the Assert that has failed with some details on why - Are you running the tests using the Test Explorer?

Comment: @DanielLoudon "But there are many Assert.IsTrue in the test"  changed to "test method" . So method can be easily understood but not the exact line.

Comment: @DanielLoudon All of the highly rated answers on your link seem to suggest otherwise.

Comment: @BradleyUffner, can you clarify ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method supports giving a message. If you do that, you will see a custom message:

```
Assert.IsTrue(yourBooleanVariable, "yourBooleanVariable was not true!")
```